# Markup and Margins

Tags: education

My question is if I can have 80% margins with 180% markup of operating costs?

For instance if I have an operating cost of 300 dollars and I mark it up by 180% I would charge the customer 540 dollars.

> > > 540 / 300
> > >       1.8

I take it that in order to make my 80% gross margins I could simply charge the customer 540.00 - it covers 100% of operating costs and allows me to collect 80% of the operating costs as the profit.

> > > ((300.00 * 1.80) - 300.0) / (300.00 * 1.80)
> > >       0.4444444444444444

The above is what we profit divided by what we take in from the customer

It seems like to get a gross margin percentage I need to profit not 80% of the operating costs but 80% of the revenue from the customer. Is this the correct way to understand this?

Below are the formulas:

- The gross profit P is the difference between the cost to make a product C and the selling price or revenue R.

  - P = R - C
- The mark up percentage M is the profit P divided by the cost C to make the product.

  - M = P / C = ( R - C ) / C
- The gross margin percentage G is the profit P divided by the selling price or revenue R.

  - G = P / R = ( R - C ) / R

Answer (score 1):

If you want gross margins of 80% it's clear from $.8=G = \frac{R-C}{R} = 1 - \frac{C}{R}$ that $C/R = .2$, which implies that $R/C = 5$.  Since $R=P + C$, we have
$$
5 = \frac{R}{C} = \frac{P + C}{C} = \frac{P}{C} + 1 = M + 1,
$$
so $M=1$ and the markup percentage should be 400%.

Answer (score 0):

If you look again at your equation for $M$, you have $M=\frac RC-1$, so if the mark up percentage is $180\%$ you should be charging $2.8 \cdot 300=840$ for an item that costs $300$.  Now your gross margin percentage is $G=\frac {840-300}{840}\approx 64.3\%$  The answer is no, a $180\%$ mark up does not support an $80\%$ gross margin.  To have $80\%$ gross margin, the cost must be $20\%$ of the selling price, so the mark up is $400\%$